# g++ -I duplicating libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++, raspberry-pi

I'm learning to program C++ in Linux, and I have the following problem:

I have 4 files: main.cpp, model.cpp, view.cpp and controller.cpp, each (except main) with their own header files. main.cpp includes model.h, view.h and controller.h, and view.h includes other libraries that are only relevant to it (necessary to run the graphic library). Those libraries are in different folders and have other dependencies on their own (that's why I don't want to move them). So, my makefile looks as follows:

```
model: model.cpp model.h
  g++ -c model.cpp

view: view.cpp view.h
  g++ -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I.. -c view.cpp

controller: controller.cpp
  g++ -c controller.cpp

main: main.cpp
  g++ -c main.cpp
```

and also a line to link all the files together (I didn't added it because I'm writing this on my Mac and copying it from the screen of my Raspberry Pi).

My problem is that when I try to compile them, all of them work, except for main, it tells me the following:

```
In file included from main.cpp:6:0:
view.h:4:23: fatal error: VG/openvg.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

From what I can understand, when I compile view with "make view", it can find the files included without problem, because it has the paths in which it must look, but since "make main" doesn't have those paths, it doesn't know where to look for openvg.h. The problem is that if I add the paths to main, it tells me that there's multiple definitions for what's inside the library... Any help?

Comment: If you're getting "multiple definitions" errors when you include the same header in multiple places, then that implies you have stuff defined in the header file that shouldn't be there.  I suggest boiling this down to a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org), and then posting the code.

Comment: Where is `VG/openvg.h`? In what sense does `view.h` "include" libraries? Does `view.h` have a header guard?

Comment: Well, it clearly can't find VG/openvg.h - where is this file, and if it's in /opt/vc/... then check that you can actually read it without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#include VG/openvg.h` is in `/opt/vc/include` and is included from `view.h`

When you `make view` you are including it from `view.cpp` which is compiled with  `-I/opt/vc/include`

When you `make main` you are including it from `main.cpp` which is compiled without flags so it can't find the file.

You need to add the flags

```
main: main.cpp
        g++ -c -I/opt/vc/include main.cpp
```

You may need the other flags as well, depending on what `view.h` includes.

The multiple definitions are caused by `$(OPENVGLIBDIR)/fontinfo.h`

which contains

```
Fontinfo SansTypeface, SerifTypeface, MonoTypeface;
```

so if you include that file in more than one object file and link them (`main.o` and `view.o` in this case) you will get multiple definitions.

Change it to

```
extern Fontinfo SansTypeface, SerifTypeface, MonoTypeface;
```

I then got Background etc undefined as libshapes is a C library.  To get round this I changed

```
#include "fontinfo.h"
#include "shapes.h"
```

in `view.h` to

```
extern "C" {
#include "fontinfo.h"
#include "shapes.h"
}
```

and it builds for me (with references to model and controller removed).

In your makefile, the view/model/controller/main targets are making the `.o` files so they should be `.o` too.  When you `make test` when no `.o` exists, it is looking for the `.o` target. If there isn't one in your makefile it will use the default which is a straight `g++ -c`.

Your make file should be like this:

```
test: model.o view.o controller.o main.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/libshapes.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/oglinit.o
    g++ -o test view.o main.o model.o controller.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/libshapes.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)oglinit.o -L/opt/vc/lib -L/opt/vc/include -lGLES -ljpeg

view.o: view.cpp
    g++ -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I.. -c view.cpp

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I.. -c main.cpp view.cpp

model.o: model.cpp
    g++ -c model.cpp

controller.o: controller.cpp
    g++ -c controller.cpp
```

Comment: when I change the make main to what you propose, now they can be compiled separately, y can make main without problem and I can also make view with problem, but the I try to link the output objects they still give me multiple definitions of whatever is inside my view.h

Comment: I could do with seeing what's in view.h or at least the errors, I don't see how you are getting multiple definitions unless you are doing something like defining non-extern global variables in the header file.

Comment: sorry, I copied the content of the files in an answer

Comment: Your view files look fine, what is the command you are using to link them and what does the first error say exactly?

Comment: I've tried several things: at this point I'm trying the following:g++ -o test main.o model.o controller.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/libshapes.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/oglinit.o -L/opt/vc/lib -lGESv2 -ljpeg

Comment: I suspect it's to do with libshapes.o or oglinit.o, remove them and just add -lOpenVG instead.  If there are undefined refs tell me what they are

Comment: I get undefined references to everything that is defined by the library (Background, Stroke, Fill, Circle, init, Start, End)

Comment: Is your code based on this example? https://github.com/ajstarks/openvg/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I've used it, and I'm getting multiple definition of `SansTypeface' and Multiple definition of `MonoTypeface

Answer (score 0):

here are my files, the code seems to run fine if in main.cpp I include view.cpp instead of view.h, but I don't think that's what I'm supposed to be doing:

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "model.h"
#include "view.h"
#include "controller.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  View view;
  view.initialize();
  view.drawBackground();
  view.show();
      std::cin >> n;
}
```

view.h:

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H

#include "VG/openvg.h"
#include "VG/vgu.h"
#include "fontinfo.h"
#include "shapes.h"

class View{
private:
    int width, height;

public:
    View();
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
        void drawBackground();
        void initialize();
        void show();
};

#endif
```

view.cpp

```
#include "view.h"

View::View(){
int width, height;
    VGfloat w2, h2, w;
}

int View::getWidth(){
return width;
}

int View::getHeight(){
return height;
}

void View::drawBackground(){

Background(0,0,0);
Stroke(255,255,255,1);
Fill(255,0,0,1.0);
Circle(width/2, height/2, 100);
}

void View::initialize(){
init(&width, &height);
Start(width, height);
}

void View::show(){
End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks A LOT for your help man! I've been fighting with this for the last couple of days (that's what I get for getting used to automatic compiling/linking). It's somewhat based on that example. I can make it run if I make each object by itself and then link them all together like this:

```
test: model.o view.o controller.o main.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/libshapes.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/oglinit.o
    g++ -o test view.o main.o model.o controller.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)/libshapes.o $(OPENVGLIBDIR)oglinit.o -L/opt/vc/lib -L/opt/vc/include -lGLES -ljpeg

view: view.cpp
    g++ -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I.. -c view.cpp

main: main.cpp
    g++ -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I.. -c main.cpp view.cpp

model: model.cpp
    g++ -c model.cpp

controller: controller.cpp
    g++ -c controller.cpp
```

if I do "make view" "make main" and then "make test" everything goes fine, but if I try "make test" without any object created prior to that I get fatal error: VG/openvg.h: No such file or directory when it's trying to compile view.cpp